# CustomPainter position changes on orientation Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a CustomPainter object which draws a line at the pointer location on pointer drag.

```
class ScribblePainter extends CustomPainter {
  Paint _paint;
  ScribblePainter(this.points, this._paint);
  final List<Offset> points;
  List<Offset> offsetPoints = List();

  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
      if (points[i] != null && points[i + 1] != null)
        canvas.drawLine(points[i], points[i + 1], _paint);
      if (points[i] != null && points[i + 1] == null) {
        offsetPoints.clear();
        offsetPoints.add(points[i]);
        offsetPoints.add(Offset(points[i].dx + 0.1, points[i].dy + 0.1));
        canvas.drawPoints(ui.PointMode.points, offsetPoints, _paint);
      }
    }
  }

  bool shouldRepaint(ScribblePainter other) => other.points != points;
}
```

Once the rotation changes, the object gets moved to a different part of the screen. I'm wondering is there any way to translate the position to be a correct one on rotation change?

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Center(
      child: DecoratedBox(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: kElevationToShadow[2],
        ),
        child: Image.memory(page.data),
      ),
    ),
    if (notes.hasData)
      for (var note in notes.data)
        Positioned.fill(
          child: CustomPaint(
            painter: ScribblePainter(
              [
                for (var offsetMap in jsonDecode(note['points']))
                  offsetMap == null
                      ? null
                      : Offset(
                          offsetMap['x'],
                          offsetMap['y'],
                        ),
              ],
              _paint,
            ),
          ),
        ),
  ],
)
```

I've tried scaling the object using Transform.scale, setting it's constraints using SizedBox, but to no avail.

Comment: Can you add this notes sample data.

Comment: List of Offset objects

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Stack in Container, give it a predefined height and width, and for image and custom painter wrap it up with Aspect ratio!
I think this will get the job done!